# Stored Procedure don't work in nHibernate

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

Goal:
retrieve data into a class with support of a stored procedure with NHibernate. You use NHibernate to retrieve the data by using stored procedure.

Problem:
I retrieve a error message saying:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException' occurred in NHibernate.dll
>
> Additional information: could not execute query
>
> [ exec sp_retrieveAllProductCategory ]
>
> [SQL: exec sp_retrieveAllProductCategory]

I dont know what to do in this context.

Information:

- http://nhibernate.info/blog/2008/11/23/populating-entities-from-stored-procedures-with-nhibernate.html
- I'm using VS 2013 and SQL Server 2012

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
    test.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="data_layer" namespace="data_layer">
  <sql-query name="sp_retrieveAllProductCategory">

    <return class="Produkt">
      <return-property column="Produkt_kategori" name="Produkt_kategori" />
      <return-property column="Produkt_kategori_ordningsnummer" name="Produkt_kategori_ordningsnummer" />
    </return>
    exec sp_retrieveAllProductCategory
  </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>


----------------------


hibernate.cfg.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=SHAREPOINT01;Initial Catalog=Active_system;Integrated Security=True</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <mapping assembly="data_layer"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>


-------------------

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Cfg;


namespace data_layer
{

    public class NhibernateDataProvider
    {

        public NhibernateDataProvider()
        {
            _sessionFactory = new Configuration().Configure().BuildSessionFactory();
            _session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }


        private ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
        private ISession _session;




        public IList<Produkt> GetAllEmployee()
        {
            return _session.CreateCriteria<Produkt>().List<Produkt>();
        }


        public void GetNamedQuery()
        {
            IQuery query = _session.GetNamedQuery("sp_retrieveAllProductCategory");


            //             IList<Product> products = query.List<Product>();

            IList<Produkt> products = query.List<Produkt>();



        }

    }

}

-------------------

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace data_layer
{
    public class Produkt
    {
        public virtual string Produkt_kategori { get; set;}
        public virtual int Produkt_kategori_ordningsnummer { get; set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Same goal but not problem situation.

Comment: OK, granted - but you should post your query and commands **as text** - not as screenshots which are next to impossible to read and understand......

Comment: If you use firefox you can right click on the picture > view image. A The original size will appear. Dont know if it works for chrome or IE.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I have applieid more text and picture to understand better.

Comment: Is there an inner exception?

Comment: yes, there is an inner exception. The message is "{"PK1_0_0_"}"

Comment: If you use chrome, right click and select "Open image in new tab" and you retrieve the original size of the picture.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
        IList<Produkt> sss = _session
                    .GetNamedQuery("sp_retrieveAllProductCategory")
                    .SetResultTransformer(
                            Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(Produkt))).List<Produkt>();
```

https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2013/09/27/nhibernate-and-stored-procedures-in-c/