# Wriong with source code for Nhibernate with stored procedure

Tags: c#, wpf, nhibernate

Goal:
Make the stored procedure to be working with nhibernate.

Problem:
I retrieve an error message:

```
could not execute query
[ exec sp_retrieveAllProductList @p0 ]
  Name:Produkt_kategori - Value:Dryck
[SQL: exec sp_retrieveAllProductList @p0]
```

What is the problem in the source code?

Info:
- Using VS 2013.

[image]

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stored Procedure don't work in nHibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23504226/stored-procedure-dont-work-in-nhibernate)

Comment: It is not a same question. maybe same goal but not same problem statement. Problem statement is not a duplicate. When I do not involve parameter, everything works well but if you use parameter, I can't receive the result.

Comment: try `.SetString("product", pProduct)` The first parameter needs to match the sql parameter.

Comment: "So why haven't you accepted the previous answer I gave if that works?" I tried your solution but it didn't work at all.

Comment: ".SetString("product", pProduct)" The error message:  Additional information: Parameter product does not exist as a named parameter in [exec sp_retrieveAllProductList :Produkt_kategori]..

Comment: It would be great if you guys could provide answer by clicking on the button Answer Your Question. I really appreciate for your previous help!

Comment: I wish you luck. Wondering why your screen shot shows your parameter as `@product` I think this is strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="data_layer" namespace="data_layer">
  <sql-query name="sp_retrieveAllProductList">
    <return-scalar column="Produkt" type="string" />
    <return-scalar column="Produkt_kategori" type="string" />    
    exec sp_retrieveAllProductList :Produkt_kategori
  </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Never forget to change the column to the right value.

Answer (score 0):

For AliasToBean to work, the returned column names (and their types) must match exactly the properties on the class to convert to.